# Japanese intransitive verbs with potential meaning

Tags: potential-form

I'm currently studying about the potential form of verbs, but what I'm curious about is the intranstive verbs with potential meaning. The blog I'm studying from had an example with the verb 見る:

"You see a sign for a bar and want to say, "Can you see that sign over there?" You might think of conjugating the verb 見る (to see) into the potential form and saying:
❌ あの看板見られる？

見られる is the potential form of the transitive verb 見る. However, in Japanese, there is an intransitive verb 見える, which means "to be in sight," and it is used for when something comes into your line of sight naturally without you trying to see it. In this case, instead of using the potential form of 見る, we use the non-potential, regular form of the intransitive verb 見える and say:

⭕️ あの看板見える？
Is the sign over there in your sight?"

So my question is if there are another intransitive verbs with potential meaning as in this example, like a list or something, I tried searching but couldn't find anything specific.

Here is the blog: [https://www.tofugu.com/japanese-grammar/verb-potential-form-reru/#:~:text=〜れる%20is%20what%20we%27re,and%20泳げる%20(can%20swim)](https://www.tofugu.com/japanese-grammar/verb-potential-form-reru/#:%7E:text=%E3%80%9C%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%20is%20what%20we%27re,and%20%E6%B3%B3%E3%81%92%E3%82%8B%20(can%20swim)).

Comment: Yes, for example stative verbs like できる. Sometimes it's not so much about the verb, but situation itself, because when we say that something happens, it implies that it's possible and similarly when something doesn't happen in volitional situations, we can say that it's not possible. For example, if we say "This box doesn't fit in the bag", it has very similar meaning to potential "can't fit".

Comment: I guess there is no specific category in traditional grammar.  [This](https://www.lang.nagoya-u.ac.jp/bugai/kokugen/nichigen/menu7_folder/symposium/pdf/4/08.pdf) refers to it as a type of 無意志動詞 along with 切れる, 割れる, 折れる.